# How does this object get to Michael Burnham?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

Partway during Discovery, Michael Burnham gets an object delivered, but

> it appears to be the telescope that both Michael and Phillipa used to observe the Klingon beacon in Episode 1.
>  This telescope should have been destroyed with the Shenzhou in the Battle of the Binary Stars
>  and there apparently was no recovery made of the Shenzhou given that a later episode has the Klingons using parts from the Shenzhou in their own plans.

The easy answer is 'continuity error ' - but is there another explanation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see from this image from [STD: Context is for Kings](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Context_Is_for_Kings_(episode)), Georgiou's 'Ready Room' and personal belongings were stripped out, presumably by the crew as they evacuated the ship.

They did however leave the (bolted down) telescope mount, implying that they were in something of a hurry and just grabbed everything that wasn't nailed to the wall.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a hand-drawn red circle for those of us who aren't sure where to look?

Comment: @Longshanks - Your wish is my crudely-drawn command